# Unable to debug httpModule of a sitefinity site hosted in IIS 8.5 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, httpmodule, sitefinity, iis-8.5

I'm trying to debug a httpModule of a sitefinity site which is hosted in IIS 8.5 using Visual Studio 2013. I'm using Sitefinity 8.1 for site development.

**Things that I've done till now:**

1. Created a httpModule under the root folder of the sitefinity site. Code as follows:

> ```
> public class UserRoleHttpModule : IHttpModule
> {            
>     public void Init(HttpApplication application)
>     {
>         application.PostAuthenticateRequest +=
>             (new EventHandler(this.PostAuthenticateRequest));
>     }
>
>     private void PostAuthenticateRequest(Object source,
>                                          EventArgs e)
>     {
>         UserManager userManager = UserManager.GetManager();
>         RoleManager roleManager = RoleManager.GetManager(SecurityManager.ApplicationRolesProviderName);
>         roleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
>
>         string[] rolesToAdd = new string[] {"BackendUsers"};
>
>         if (userManager.UserExists("rahuln"))
>         {
>             User user = userManager.GetUser("rahuln");
>
>             foreach (var roleName in rolesToAdd)
>             {
>                 if (roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
>                 {
>                     Role role = roleManager.GetRole(roleName);
>                     roleManager.AddUserToRole(user, role);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         roleManager.SaveChanges();
>         roleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = false;
>     }          
>
>     public void Dispose()
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Registered module under webconfig

> ```
> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">        
>             <remove name="UserRoleHttpModule" />
>             <add name="UserRoleHttpModule" type="SitefinityWebApp.UserRoleHttpModule"/>
> </modules>
> ```

Now when I run the page from IIS and do the "attach to process" with w3wp.exe in visual studio. I never get a hit on my break points in httpModule. I tried building the solution and the build was successful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the project in Debug mode? Is Compilation debug="true" in web.config?

Comment: Can someone delete this, I tried entering a carriage return and it submitted my comment. I moved my question into an answer so I can apply formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the HttpModule is executing, to verify add the following to PostAuthenticateRequest and it should redirect to microsoft.com if it is.

```
HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
HttpContext context = application.Context;
context.Response.Redirect("http://www.microsoft.com");
```